# How do I get Visual Express 2010 to find my python.h header file?

Tags: c++, python, visual-c++-2010-express

I already did a search, but I just couldn't find what I searched for.
I want to create a Python Module using C++ and Visual C++ Express 2010.
Now, I need to include Python.h, but when I compile it says it couldn't find Python.h. How do I give my VC the Python header file ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tell IDE where header is located:

Project -> Properties -> C/C++ -> Additional Include Directories

Comment: Thank you this did it. But now it tells me `fatal error LNK1104: File "python27_d.lib" could not be opened.`

Comment: @Niklas if you have file named 'python27_d.lib' also tell IDE about it: Project -> Properties -> Linker -> Additional Library Directories

Comment: I don't have any file named like this. This must be because of the include, i think ? This is my only code for now: `#include <Python.h> \n int main() { return 0; }`

Comment: @Niklas i mean in your API Python package from where you using Python.h. Maybe you have to build it

Comment: I'm very new to C++. how do I build it ? Thanks !

Comment: @Niklas review this [docs](http://docs.python.org/extending/windows.html). Try to build not Debug but Release type of your project as i see necessary lib (python27.lib) is present in \Python27\libs\

Comment: Thanks I'm going it through step by step.
But again a problem in step 3 of this document. I can't build the example.dll it always tells me that "C:\Python27\Source\example_nt\.\Debug\example.dll" couldn't be found O_o
I cannot find anything on the internet
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You either have to set the path to to the python include files in your IDE. Navigate to `Tools | Options | Projects and Solutions | VC++ Directories` and add the path under `Include Directories`.