# the python header file for c++ gives an "cannot open source file" error which i am unable to solve

Tags: python, c++

I want to write an c++ program that can access an python file. but to start I need to add`#include<Python.h>` which gives me an error: cannot open source file. I really have no idea at how to solve this. could it be that my python path is not set correctly? Because it could be that i set the windows path variable wrong

Comment: If you are using Visual Express, then you may find your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6613039/10553341

Comment: Solved it, it appeard that my device just DIDN'T have the file at all, i have python 3.7 installed and it didn't come with the file. but now that i installed python 2.7.13 i do have the file